# Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable; 498

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to run a simple script but I get an error

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator
###from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook

dag = DAG(
    'auto',
    schedule_interval='0 17 * * *', 
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 20, 2),
    tags=['error'],
    catchup=False,
)

get_all_countries = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id="prueba_consulta",
        mssql_conn_id="sqlserver",
        sql=r"""select * from Tbl_Personas where PersonaId ='155133';""",
         dag=dag,
    )
```

I run the dag and I get the following error Failed to execute job 29 for task query_test (Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable; 498)

another way was

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

dag = DAG(
    'consultar',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=datetime(2023,1,20,2),
    tags=['prueba'],
    catchup=False,
)
def mssql_func(**kwargs):
    hook = MsSqlHook(conn_id='sqlserver')
    df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql="select * from [SIICON].[dbo].[Tbl_Personas] where PersonaId ='155133' ")
    #do whatever you need on the df


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='mssql_task',
    python_callable=mssql_func,
    dag=dag
)
```

I got the following error Failed to execute job 22 for task mssql_task (The conn_id `mssql_default` isn't defined; 2002